# Android Gradle 4.1-rc-1 Not Found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1, I'm required to use Gradle 4.1-rc-1. AS offered to do the update for me (why not) but when the project tries to build, I get an error saying the pom and jar for gradle-4.1-rc-1. It's apparently not in the jcenter or google repos. On [Google's AS release page](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-1.html), they mention this is a known bug and that a clean and sync should fix it, but it did not work for me.

Here is my build file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1-rc-1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Which repository holds the correct gradle files? Should they have downloaded to my machine already?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should update your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file of your project, instead of `build.gradle`.

Here is my content of `gradle-wrapper.properties`: 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip`. Content of `build.gradle` : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'`.

Comment: Yes, this is a good point as it seems counterintuitive to have one spot say `4.1-rc-1` and another say `3.0.0-beta1`. I understand that one refers to Gradle and the other refers to the AS plugin, but I don't believe the "automatic update" option takes this into account and just puts `4.1-rc-1` in both places.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working although I'm not exactly sure what did it. However, here are some things I did and some extra information if anyone else is running into this issue as well.

**Project Settings (⌘;)**

Gradle Version: 4.1

Android Plugin Version: 3.0.0-beta1

Android Plugin Repository: google(), jcenter

Default Library Repository: google(), jcenter, 'https://jitpack.io'

With these settings, upon trying to sync, I would be asked to update my Gradle to 4.1-rc-1. I pressed the "do it manually" option. Then I went to my project in the terminal and did what google suggested:

`gradlew clean`

`gradlew assemble`